# Polymer template repeat not working

Tags: javascript, polymer

I've created a custom element and setting the `repeat` attribute on the root `template` doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
<link rel="import" href="/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="cr-tracks">
    <template repeat="{{track in tracks}}">
        {{foo}}
        {{track.title}}
    </template>

    <style>

    </style>

    <script>
        Polymer('cr-tracks', {
            ready: function() {
                this.tracks = [
                    {
                        title: "Example Title",
                        artist: "Example Artist"
                    }
                ];
            },
            foo: 'bar'
        })
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

`bar`, the value of `foo` is displayed, but nothing is rendered for `track.title`. I can access it directly via `tracks[0].title`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the special outer template. Polymer sets up the outer template by setting the model to be the element instance itself.

Try this:

```
<polymer-element name="cr-tracks">
  <template>

    <template repeat="{{track in tracks}}">
      {{foo}}
      {{track.title}}
    </template>

    <style>
    </style>

  </template>
  <script>
    ...
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```